# Why doesn't work revalidate in page.jsx, but it is revalidated in dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using the revalidate in Next.js 13.

Consider the example below :

Suppose we have two paths in the **app folder**, One is `/services/page.jsx` and the other `/services/[slug]/page.jsx`

I wrote inside the `/services/page.jsx` file:

```
async function getData() {
    const res = await fetch('https://<domain>/product_categories_list/',{ next: { revalidate: 60 } } );
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
}

const Services = async () => {
  const data = await getData();

  return (
    <>
      <ServicesComp data={data} />
    </>
  );
};
export default Services ;
```

the code above will not be revalidate.

But the same code structure is revalidate in `/services/[slug]/page.jsx` path.

I tried all the ways to revaldiate a route, but I didn't find the one that solves my problem